# How should be interactions with non-mehram be like in a coed institution?

Tags: practical-islam, fiqh, islamic-philosophy, non-mahram, education

How should young muslim brothers ad sisters interact in a coed high school? 
What are the things we must be aware of to protect ourselves from any evils in such an atmosphere?

Comment: Try to avoid interaction as much as possible with the opposite gender unless it's something necessary and serious. Any conversation should be empty of anything that makes the conversation "fun" I would say. Because when there is "fun" in the matter, satan starts his evil whispers.

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to follow your instincts - if it feels wrong, then it feels as such for a reason. I do not think (as has been suggested) that your conversation need be devoid of "fun", though others should know where you stand, and all inappropriate matters/conversation ought to be ended swiftly.

I agree that the rules in the previous post are sensible, yet they focus on preventing the occurrance of difficult situations, such as being alone with members of the opposite gender. However, in life I feel these rules are unlikely to suffice - rather, practice complete control over your thoughts and actions so that these situations do not lead you toward evil. Put simply, strength of will and character will see you through many difficult situtations.

I find the best approach is to be reserved, keep conversation focused on the task at hand, and refrain from engaging in anything other than polite conversation. Then, analyze your behaviour throughout the situation retrospectively, and determine what you would say/ not say next time. I hope my advice helps to suppliment the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain rules you have to follow:

1. Recite Daily morning and evening supplications to get help against devil
2. Try your best never to be alone with any guy
3. Wear proper hijab (including niqab)
4. Dont be Frank or open with any guy (in case there is need to talk)
5. Stay to the point (if you have to talk about study material)
6. If in any case you sense that a guy is interested in you, then try your best to avoid him as much as possible.

Hope it helps